# what is the best strategy to use el-get for emacs behind company firewall?

Tags: emacs, el-get

I am using emacs almost exclusively as text editor and IDE for multiple languages at home but would like to be able to use / share my existing emacs setup at work as well.

My setup is making use of el-get, which works great when I am at home but fails to install when I am at work because of firewall, etc. (I tried to setup the http proxies, etc - it is still failing).

What is the best strategy to use el-get behind the company's firewall? Or is it better to put entire el-get folder into github repo?

Comment: Why not just bring in your entire setup on a USB thumb drive and copy it to your work computer?

Comment: I certainly recommend putting your entire emacs config under version control, el-get directory included. Some operate on the assumption that upstream packages will always be available and always be in a compatible working state, but I prefer to maintain a known working config (and be able to roll anything back with ease).

Comment: most companies these days won't allow you to use USB flash drives (e.g. companies in financial sector)

Comment: If you're not allowed to use USBs, sneaking around the firewall using an http proxy is likely also forbidden. If you do have access to github that would be a reasonable approach.